# The integral about probability measures

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

**Definition** For a discrete group $\Gamma$, we let Prob$(\Gamma)$ be the space of all probability measures on $\Gamma$:
$$Prob(\Gamma)=\{\mu\in l^{1}(\Gamma): \mu\geq0,~\sum\limits_{t\in\Gamma}\mu(t)=1\}.$$

Now we set $F(\mu, r)=\{t\in \Gamma:~\mu(t)>r\}$. Can we conclude that $\int_0 ^1 |F(\mu,~r)|dr=1$? (Here, $|.|$ is the cardinal number of set.)

Comment: This seems rather unlikely given that $|F(\mu, r)| \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.  Why would you expect this to happen?

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan I read a book, and the author use this property directly in the proof a theorem, but I do not know why this equation hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a statement $P$ let $[P]$ denote $1$ if $P$ is true and $0$ if it's false. We have:

$$
\int_0^1 |F(\mu,r)|\;dr =\int_0^1 \sum_{t\in \Gamma} [\mu(t)>r]\;dr = \sum_{t\in\Gamma}  \int_0^1 [\mu(t)>r] \;dr = \sum_{t\in\Gamma} \mu(t) = 1.
$$

Comment: Why does the last equation
 hold ? Do you mean $\int_0^1 [\mu(t)>r] \;dr = \mu(t) $?

Comment: 1) The last equation, $\sum_{t\in\Gamma} \mu(t) = 1$, holds because $\mu$ is assume to be a probability measure on the discrete set $\Gamma$.
2) For your other question, $\int_0^1 [\mu(t)>r] \;dr = \mu(t)$ is true simply because the integrand is the characteristic function of the interval $[0, \mu(t))$ so its integral is equal to the length of that interval, $\mu(t)$.

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks very much.